# pycluster installation with canopy

Tags: python, canopy

I have canopy (free version) installed and trying to install pycluster downloaded from http://bonsai.hgc.jp/~mdehoon/software/cluster/software.htm#ctv

Ran python setup.py install, but its not working. What can be the solution?

Comment: can you share the system logs ?

Comment: @aberna, this is the message from cmd, not able to install mingw:     
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'Pycluster.cluster' extension
error: Could not find Visual Studio 2008 in your path.

If you do not have Visual Studio 2008 installed, you can use
the MinGW compiler instead. To install mingw, do:
    enpkg mingw
To use the MinGW compiler to build an extension module, use
the '-c' flag, e.g.:
    python setup.py build_ext -c mingw64
Note that building Python extensions with MinGW is not officially
supported, although it is known to work in many cases.

Comment: Because Python and all the provided libraries are build with VS 2008, Enthought strongly recommends not using mingw for building your c extensions. Library incompatibilities may cause difficult to track bugs and crashes. Mingw mostly works on toy problems.

Answer (score 0):

Make Canopy Python be your default Python, then run Gohlke's installer for pycluster: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycluster

For context and more details, see https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-User-Python-from-the-OS-command-line